# How to force a solution file (.sln) to be opened in the configured Visual Studio version?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I have both Visual Studio 2013 and 2015 installed. On some projects, I want to use Visual Studio 2015. If unspecified or on new projects I want to use Visual Studio 2015. But on some projects I want to stick to Visual Studio 2013 for compatibility reasons with other plugins and libraries that don't work with Visual Studio 2015.

The solution files I have that I want to open in 2013 are configured for 2013, as such:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
```

However, when I double-click them, they automatically open in Visual Studio 2015, and then get compiler errors in the non-compatible libraries. To open them in 2013, I have to open the application Visual Studio 2013 and then open the project from inside Visual Studio 2013.

From what I understand after some searching, the most commonly desired behaviour is the one I presently have - to open everything in Visual Studio 2015 despite the solution file being configured for 2013. But I don't want that.

Is there any way to configure the Visual Studio version selector on the desired behaviour?

Comment: Not really a full solution but you could create a batch file for each solution, pointing to open the solution in the right VS version and open them that way. Alternatively, you could write a quick .exe that parses the .sln file and chooses the best VS version to run, then set that .exe as the default program for opening .slns

Comment: It already works this way.  The default file association for a .sln file is with the "Visual Studio Launcher".  An otherwise well-hidden program that reads the .sln file and determines which VS version to start, based on the Format Version.  How this got broken can't be guessed from the question.